# The transform is not yet moving to target and become child smoothly. Why when the player hand is up the movement is not smooth?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

A bit long but all connected. I can add a short video clip that shows the problem when the hand is outstretched or some screenshots.

The Animator component is no the Player, not the transform(NAVI) so I don't want to disable/enable the Animator on the Player.

If the player's hand is down in its natural state, the transform moves to the player's hand and smoothly becomes a child of the hand.  but if the hand is up pointing the transform then the movement is not smooth anymore.

The player has these components:

Animator , Rigidbody , Capsule collider , Third Person Character , Third Person User Control , Ik Control script that use the player rig to change the hand state position using weight.

This script is moving the transform to the player hand :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NaviManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public enum TransitionState
    {
        None,
        MovingTowards,
        Transferring
    }

    public Transform player;
    public Transform carte;
    public Animation anim;
    public Transform destinationTransform;
    public float speed;
    public float distanceToStop;
    public float lerpTime;
    public string childState;

    private GameObject rig_f_middle;
    private Transform originTransform;
    private float timer;
    private bool openonce = false;
    private TransitionState state = TransitionState.MovingTowards;
    private InteractableItem naviInteractableItem;

    void Start()
    {
        rig_f_middle = GameObject.Find("rig_f_middle.02.R");
        destinationTransform = rig_f_middle.transform;

        naviInteractableItem = GetComponent<InteractableItem>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        var dist = Vector3.Distance(carte.position, player.position);

        if (dist < 1.7f)
        {
            if (openonce == false)
            {
                anim.Play("Crate_Open");
                openonce = true;
            }

            if (openonce)
            {
                switch (state)
                {
                    case TransitionState.MovingTowards:
                        var v = rig_f_middle.transform.position - transform.position;
                        if (v.magnitude < 0.001f)
                        {
                            state = TransitionState.Transferring;
                            originTransform = rig_f_middle.transform;
                            timer = 0;
                            return;
                        }
                        Vector3 moveDir = v.normalized;
                        transform.position += moveDir * speed * Time.deltaTime;

                        break;

                    case TransitionState.Transferring:
                        timer += Time.deltaTime;
                        this.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(originTransform.position, destinationTransform.position, timer);
                        if (timer >= 1.0f)
                        {
                            this.transform.parent = destinationTransform;
                            state = TransitionState.None;

                            if (naviInteractableItem != null)
                            {
                                naviInteractableItem.distance = 0f;
                            }

                            this.enabled = false;
                            return;
                        }

                        break;

                    default:
                        this.enabled = false;
                        return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This part of the script from the Ik Control is changing the hand state pointing towards a target :

```
if ((primaryTarget != null) && !transitionToNextTarget)
        {
            if (primaryTarget.IsAnyAction())//.interactableMode == InteractableItem.InteractableMode.ActionWithoutThrow)
            {
                RightHandToTarget = true;
            }

            lastPrimaryTarget = primaryTarget;
            finalLookWeight = Mathf.Lerp(finalLookWeight, 1f, Time.deltaTime * weightDamping);
            float bodyWeight = finalLookWeight * .1f;
            animator.SetLookAtWeight(finalLookWeight, bodyWeight, 1f);
            animator.SetLookAtPosition(primaryTarget.transform.position);

            if (RightHandToTarget && primaryTarget.IsAnyAction())
            {
                Vector3 relativePos = primaryTarget.transform.position - transform.position;
                Quaternion rotationtoTarget = Quaternion.LookRotation(relativePos, Vector3.up);

                if (primaryTarget.interactableMode == InteractableItem.InteractableMode.ActionWithoutThrow)
                {
                    animator.SetIKRotationWeight(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, finalLookWeight);
                    animator.SetIKRotation(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, rotationtoTarget);
                    animator.SetIKPositionWeight(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, finalLookWeight * 1f * closestLookWeight);
                    animator.SetIKPosition(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, primaryTarget.transform.position);
                }

                if (primaryTarget.interactableMode == InteractableItem.InteractableMode.Action)
                {
                    animator.SetIKRotationWeight(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, finalLookWeight);
                    animator.SetIKRotation(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, rotationtoTarget);
                    animator.SetIKPositionWeight(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, finalLookWeight * 0.1f * closestLookWeight);
                    animator.SetIKPosition(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, primaryTarget.transform.position);
                }

                // -> new code block
                if (finalLookWeight > 0.95f) // here you can play with a value between 0.95f -> 1.0f
                {
                    if (primaryTarget.interactableMode == InteractableItem.InteractableMode.Action
                        && hasSent == false)
                    {
                        target = primaryTarget;
                        toTarget = true;
                        hasSent = true;
                        primaryTarget.description = "";
                        // Here I need to find where to make hasSent false again.
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    hasSent = false;
                }

                if (finalLookWeight > 0.9f)
                {
                    handFinishedMove = true;
                }
            }
        }
```

This is a link for the full IK Control script it's a bit long :

https://pastebin.com/nn8E2qS4